# error while deploying my a react js project

Tags: reactjs, deployment, symlink

My build keeps failing when I try to deploy my project. The error:

> "Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /home/name/HUMMINGBIRD/hummingbird/src/assets/Heropic.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported."

but I don't understand this error as the file mentioned is in the `src` folder, and when I try to use a relative path, i.e.:

```js
import facebook from "src/assets/facebook.png"
```

I get this error

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/assets/facebook.png' in '/home/name/HUMMINGBIRD/hummingbird/src/Components/Footer'
> ERROR in ./src/Components/Footer/Footer.js 6:0-47
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/assets/facebook.png' in '/home/name/HUMMINGBIRD/hummingbird/src/Components/Footer'"

The deployment service I'm using suggested using `symlinks` but admittedly I don't fully understand them yet.

What should I do?

This is how I'm importing the images inside the react project:

```js
import React from "react";
import "/home/name/HUMMINGBIRD/hummingbird/src/Components/Footer/Footer.css";
import facebook from "/home/name/HUMMINGBIRD/hummingbird/src/assets/facebook.png"; 
import instagram from "/home/name/HUMMINGBIRD/hummingbird/src/assets/instagram.png"; 
import linkedin from "/home/name/HUMMINGBIRD/hummingbird/src/assets/linkedin.png"; 
import twitter from "/home/name/HUMMINGBIRD/hummingbird/src/assets/twitter.png";
```

Comment: can you show the jsx file, how do you import the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the way you are importin the images is wrong.
The way to import the image is to go back from the file position to the image position.

for example:

If my folder structure looks like this:

```
root
- src
-- assets
--- images
---- myImage.png
-- components
--- MyCustomComp
---- index.jsx
-- pages
-- util
...
```

So inside index.jsx, we will import images from the assets folder this way:

```
import myImage from "../../assets/images/myImage.png"
```

every `../` is one directory up. from index.jsx to go up to assets we need to go two directories up. `../../` , this will put us in the src folder. now we can access the assets folder -> images -> myImage.png

if the file/image is inside the same folder with the index.jsx - then you just need `./`

Its true not only for images, but for any other file.

Comment: If this answer helped you , please mark it as the answer by clicking on the V next to the answer.